# compare a string array in mongodb collection.find()

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I've the following code:

```
public class Compagny
{
    [BsonElement("compagnyName")]
    public string[] CompagnyName { get; set; }
}


public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Film>>> GetAllFilms([FromBody] Compagny compagny)
{
    var toReturn = await _filmCollection.Find(item => item.CompagnyOwner == compagny.CompagnyName[0]).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(toReturn);
}
```

A user can be registered in multiple compagnies but with "compagny.CompagnyName[0]" i'm only able to get all the movies from the [index]'s compagny.

Do you guys know a simple way to compare and get all the movies from all the users's compagnies?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var toReturn = await _filmCollection.Find(item => item.CompagnyOwner == compagny.CompagnyName.Contains(item.CompagnyOwner)).ToListAsync();
```